# In a single word, how can you describe something as being made by women for women?

Tags: single-word-requests

Can we say "for women and by women" in a single word? 
We're creating a service that is similar to uber but only for women.

Thank you very much.

Comment: *Forwomenandbywomen*.

Comment: Can you give us any more context as to what sort of service you want to say is "for women and by women"?

Comment: @DanBron - You took the word right out of my mouth.

Comment: - - Sorority - -

Comment: Please supply more context. Please also supply the reason why you need a single word. @DanBron may have been joking, but you *can* actually use "women-for-women", or "by-women-for-women", and these *are* single words. But why do you need a single word? And why a single word for these particular words in what you're writing, and not others?

Comment: This word doesn't exactly mean what you're looking for - but, it sure SOUNDS like it does... plus, it's pretty obscure so you could probably even use it as a trademark or brand-name:  GYNARCHY.  (If not, how about "vagina-centric"?)

Comment: What's with all the downvotes (on the question _and_ answers)? This is no more unreasonable than many other single word requests.

Comment: Thanks Mitch, that's what happen when Internet is in the hand of frustrated 12 years olds.

Comment: @Oldbag FYI, as a consumer, I am unlikely to buy anything with a GYNARCHY trademark. That just sounds terrible.

Comment: @Kyle: Me too. And I wouldn't call "gynarchy" obscure either. I use it all the time, especially with one friend, to denote a state of affairs from which we have both emigrated. OTOH, OP might usefully coin a word that starts in "gyn" and ends in something else (not "rule"!), depending on what his product is. Oh, okay, taxis. What is the Greek root for "transport", or what is Ancient Greek for "carriage"?

Comment: By [gender] and **only** for [gender] is called [*discrimination*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discrimination) if the product or service is applicable to either gender.

Comment: Abraham Lincoln used *"of the people, by the people, and for the people"*.  I doubt there is a single word meaning *"by and for"*.

Comment: @mazura - yes, pointing out any particular group that is already discriminated against does make one concerned about further discrimination. But there might be some situations where the for us by us name is desired (say a women's sports club where no one want a bunch of dudes gawking). Of course, that a dude is looking for such a word might make one question things (like a senate subcommitte on women's issues being run only by men)

Comment: @AymaneShuichi - if you're creating this service, there will be lots of other people who enjoy a little gender wordplay (even your users!).  With respect and friendliness, I'd suggest learning to laugh it off :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Women-only service***

from The Economist
: ***[Women-only](http://www.economist.com/news/united-states/21620229-new-car-service-offers-lifts-women-women-fare-ladies) cabs.***

> A new car service offers lifts for women, from women.
>
> ...the launch of SheTaxis, an app that lets female passengers insist on female drivers, and vice versa.

Comment: Our service is very similar to shecab

Comment: @AymaneShuichi - a single word for describing the concept may create misundestandings, that's why I suggested the one used in the article. I think it is clear and unambiguous if referred to a service done and meant by and for women.

Comment: -1 Japan has women-only train carriages, which implies nothing about who creates or runs the service, only who can use it.

Comment: @Aymane: nobody at all laughed at your question. People asked you for clarification. (How hard would it have been to just tell us right away that your service is similar to shecabs?) But you never made any effort to improve the question. So understandably, downvotes started to trickle in to give you an incentive to work on it. But even after that, you still refused to invest any effort into improving the question. Instead you chose to insult people trying to make this site a better place as "frustrated 12 year olds". You are being rude. (And yet *still* nobody is laughing at your question.)

Comment: I relied on Stackexchange's tags : single-word-requests
I explained what I wanted, and didn't know that you guys would be curious about the service we're offering.
What would you react to an answer like : Forwomenandbywomen. ????
He's making fun of my question and is playing cool. I consider that as laughing at my question.

Comment: To provide some perhaps useful background context, see http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g

Answer (score -1):

*[Feminine](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/feminine)* does the job:

> adjective
>   1.1 Relating to women; female:
>
> *ODO*

Tracking the connotations at [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=feminine&allowed_in_frame=0):

> mid-14c., "of the female sex,"  from Old French femenin (12c.)
>   "feminine, female; with feminine qualities, effeminate,"
>   from Latin
>   femininus "feminine" (in the grammatical sense at first),
>   from femina
>   "woman, female," literally "she who suckles,"
>   from root of felare "to
>   suck, suckle" (see fecund).
>   Usual modern sense of "woman-like, proper
>   to or characteristic of women" is recorded from mid-15c. Related:
>   Femininely.
>
> The **interplay of meanings** now represented roughly in female
>   "characteristic of the sex that bears children," feminine "having
>   qualities considered appropriate to a woman," and effeminate "having
>   female qualities in a bad sense, unmanly," and the attempt to keep
>   them clear of each other, has led to many coinages. Among nouns, in
>   addition to feminity "womanishness," femininity, femaleness,
>   feminineness (1810, "female qualities"), there is feminitude (1878);
>   feminility "womanliness" (1824); feminie "womankind" (late 14c.);
>   femality (17c., "effeminacy;" 1754 "female nature"); feminacy "female
>   nature" (1829); feminicity "quality or condition of being a woman"
>   (1843). Also feminality (1640s, "quality or state of being female"),
>   from rare adjective feminal "female, belonging to a woman" (late
>   14c.), from Old French feminal. And femineity "quality or state of
>   being feminine," also "effeminate; womanly," from Latin femineus "of a
>   woman, pertaining to a woman."
>
> **Emphasis** mine

Comment: But that doesn't imply that something is made by women or even exclusively for women. For example, most people would probably agree that nail polish is "feminine," yet it can be made by men and is sometimes used by males as well as females.

Comment: Yes, men can invade feminine territory, but it is still feminine territory. Unfortunately, gender confusion has an impact on words too.

Comment: But "feminine territory" is much broader than "made for and by females," which is what OP is looking for. Plenty of things produced by men could well be called feminine, so the word isn't specific enough to answer the question.

Comment: "Yes, men can invade feminine territory, but it is still feminine territory." That...that is too non-PC even for me, and I'm no fan of political correctness.

Comment: By *non-PC*, may I assume you mean *politically **in**correct*, @KyleStrand? If your opinion is correct, and mine is incorrect simply because it isn't yours, perhaps you are a bigger fan of political correctness than you thought.

Comment: @ScotM I didn't say that my opinion is "correct." I said that your statement is politically incorrect. This is a judgment of tone as much as it is of your factual claim: "invade" is pretty strong language to describe wearing nail polish!

Comment: We's cool then, @KyleStrand :-) I found the bizarre timbre of the entire question-answer-comment conversation quite entertaining.